# Sheets - Determine Cell Number with Equation

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reference a cell by the following equation:

```
=A(51-(48-(COUNTIF(Info!A5:A52,"*"))))
```

A51 is the last possible cell that information could be in (hence the 51). 48 is the total number of entries that can be in this list, and the COUNTIF bit determines how many entries have been made (thus ignoring the blank cells). Problem is, Sheets doesn't like the "A(…" part.

What I'm trying to do is use the equation to tell Sheets to grab whatever data is in this cell. The cell will be located column A for sure, but the equation is determining the last cell that's been filed in the line of 48 (in range A4:A51). I'm also going to be altering the equation to pull the last 5 entries in the list. So I supposed there's really two questions here:

1. How do I get Sheets to cooperate?
2. Is this the most effective way to grab this data?

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me the answer, but on the wrong question, so I'm posting it here.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(51-(48-(COUNTIF(Info!A5:A52,"*")))))
```